# JBoss7: class configured for SSLContext: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLS10Context not a SSLContext

Tags: java, database-connection, classpath, jboss7.x

I am developing an application which is a standalone application and gonna package it as a jar file (Which is lika a `OSGi Plugin`) and will deploy that `jar into JBoss`.

When I run my application in my eclipse the application works fine. In Jboss It throws error.

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.Node`.

If I add `rt.jar` to `WEB-INF/lib` folder and deploy into Jboss. That error no longer thrown. But I got a new exception Even I added `jsse.jar` to `lib`  but unable to resolve the error.

```
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a 
 secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. 
 Error: "class configured for SSLContext: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLS10Context 
 not a SSLContext".
  ......

 Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for 
 SSLContext: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLS10Context not a SSLContext

 06:10:53,484 ERROR [stderr] (default-short-running-threads-threads - 26) at     
 sun.security.jca.GetInstance.checkSuperClass(GetInstance.java:258)

 06:10:53,484 ERROR [stderr] (default-short-running-threads-threads - 26) at    
 sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:237)

 06:10:53,484 ERROR [stderr] (default-short-running-threads-threads - 26) at  
 sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)

 06:10:53,484 ERROR [stderr] (default-short-running-threads-threads - 26) at  
 javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:156)

 06:10:53,500 ERROR [stderr] (default-short-running-threads-threads - 26) at   
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1353)
```

My Development environment is `Jdk1.7` , `Windows XP` and `Eclipse Juno` The server Environment is also same as my local environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. dont ever package rt.jar (or any other java built-in) as part of your deployment. it causes classloading issues and weird errors - like the one youre experiencing now.
2. what you need to do is declare your dependency on the dom API in your jar's manifest. this has been [asked already on the jboss forums](https://community.jboss.org/thread/228066?_sscc=t). the solution is to have an "Import-Package" key in your top-level artifact's (*.ear/*.war etc) manifest file with the value `org.w3c.dom.Node;resolution:="optional"`

edit: or you could switch your DOM-parsing code to rely on an external library not provided with the jdk like [dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/) and include that as a library

Comment: I dont have Manifest file in my .jar

Comment: could you post the contents of the manifest file as part of the question?

Comment: Myapplication does not have a Manifest file as it is deployed as a plugin into a BPM tool which runs on JBoss. @radai

Comment: When I remove rt.jar I got the following exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.Node @radai

Comment: It worked. The problem is I did not add xml-apis jar file to META-INF\lib directory.

Answer (score 8):

Also try to add
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.net.ssl.*")
as class annotation. Worked for me.